# How to avoid generating unwanted blank columns when looping through Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, database, pandas

I've learnt much from the stackoverflow community, thanks to all of you. I can't find an answer to this question anywhere so I'd appreciate your help.

I have created a smallish database (899 * 10) of scientific papers. I want to write a script to print the title and abstract of each, and then make a (human, non-automatable) decision to include or not include in a systematic review.

I have come close with the following script, which allows me to update the 'decision' column for each paper, and to save and exit so I don't have to do it all at once.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print "Please type the path of the database you would like to assess"
path = raw_input('>>> ')

data = pd.read_csv(path)

if 'jim_decision' not in data:
        data['jim_decision'] = pd.Series(np.nan)


def decision_maker(dataframe):
        current_row = 0
        while True:
                if pd.isnull(dataframe['jim_decision'][current_row]):
                        print "\n\n Title:\n\n %s \n Abstract:\n s\n\n\n" % (dataframe.Title[current_row], dataframe.Abstract[current_row])
                        decision = raw_input("From the title and abstract, should this article be included for review of full manuscript?\n\nType 'Y' or 'N', or 'Save' to exit: ")     

                        if decision == 'Save':  
                                dataframe.to_csv(path)
                                print "Your changes have been saved"
                                break
                        else: 
                                dataframe['jim_decision'][current_row] = decision
                                current_row += 1
decision_maker(data)
```

However, for some reason, every time I run it, I get an extra column called 'Unnamed: [X]', simply containing the index number, added before the first pandas column. I can't work out where it comes from, how to get rid of it, or whether (as I presume) it risks contaminating the data.

I'm fairly new to all this, so I'm sure this isn't very pretty or pythonic, but I'm just trying to learn to use python/pandas to make my research life easier... Any input would be gratefully received!

Comment: don't you have trailing blanks at the end of lines in the csv file you open?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means exactly... Sorry, I'm new at this! The csv has 9 columns of all the same length, if that's what you're getting at?

Comment: so at the end of the lines in the csv, you have blanks like space characters. If the columns are of fixed length, prefer `read_fwf` than `read_csv`

Comment: Can you add an example of `data` dataframe?

Comment: Thanks Boud! I tried this, and it had the same effect, but then trying it made me realise that the .to_csv was saving a new column with the index at the front every time I ran the method (obvious in retrospect), so I've added index=False as an arg and sorted it. Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone comes across this in future, pandas saves the index of the data frame by default as a new column.

If you don't want this, run include the `index=False argument`, for example: `df.to_csv('./filepath.csv', index=False)`